# Cubecart Search Results- Product Names above HTML Tag

Tags: php, html, e-commerce

I do not know anything about CubeCart! But I was asked to add a search form to the sidebar of a website...

The search results work fine - however, it seems to be spitting every product name above the  tag?!

I can't work out why this is happening - see below!

[image]

Comment: Here is the URL: http://bit.ly/uNye4Y - MODERATORS DO NOT REMOVE AS THIS IS CONFIDENTIAL.

Comment: It looks like elements of your <head> is rending inside the <body>. usually it is because of not nesting the tags properly. Please check your tags once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On search results page contents of  are not inside the head instead these are inside , usually this is because of incorrect nesting of tags. I can not see template files or server-side files so can not tell you exactly where are you missing some thing. 
[image]

Comment: It appears above like you said in the firebug window, if you view source on the page, the tags appear to be nesting correctly. I can confirm that the /global/index.tpl file is fine aswell.